# Scroll Iframe on IPhone

Tags: iphone, iframe, scroll

I have a web app that wraps the main site content in an Iframe to enable some elements that are persistent across the site (only way to do what I'm after as far as I can tell).

It works fine on most browsers, but there is a scrolling problem on the Iphone: The content displays, but trying to scroll does a drag and drop operation instead.

Is there any way to tell the Iphone browser to use normal scrolling in that specific Iframe?

Example site: http://carlocapocasa.com

Thanks a ton and a half,

Carlo

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Use two fingers to scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems getting an iframe to scroll on iOS devices. My iframe was inside a DIV, which had it's overflow set to hidden.

My solution was to set the overflow of the containing DIV to visible.